# Laptop won't wake from USB or will wake up immediately

Tags: usb, power-management

I have a USB keyboard at `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3` - where `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1` is a hub. I'd like to be able to wake the laptop up using this keyboard, without opening the lid (currently opening the lid does wake correctly).

In this setup, keyboard does not perform wakeup:

```
# grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/{usb1,1-1,1-1.3}/power/wakeup
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3/power/wakeup:enabled
```

However, if I enable `power/wakeup` for `usb1` as well, the laptop immediately wakes up after going to sleep, without any input. I've tested this with a couple of keyboards.

How can I debug this?